# Shall I include css and js in angular-cli or index.html in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am working on `angular 2` project. We can include `css` and `js` in `angular-cli.json` and we can also include it in `index.html` file.
But which one is better and why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always write it in angular-cli.json..!

Its a config file through which index.html will be populated based on your configs in angular-cli.json, which is managed by webpack.

Comment: Do you have any references to official docs substantiating this?